# segmentation total based on multiple condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, segment

data frame:-

```
ID spend month_diff    
12  10    -1         
12  10    -2         
12  20     1        
12  30     2         
13  15    -1         
13  20    -2        
13  25     1        
13  30     2
```

I want to get the spend_total based on the month difference for a particular ID. month_diff in negative means spend done by customer in last year and positive means this year.so,i want to compare the spend of customers for past year and this year. so the conditions are as follows:

Conditions:-

```
if month_diff >= -2 and < 0 then cumulative spend for negative months - flag=pre
if month_diff > 0 and <=2 then  cumulative spend for positive months  - flag=post
```

Desired data frame:-

```
ID spend month_diff tot_spend   flag    
12  10    -2         20         pre
12  30     2         50         post
13  20    -2         35         pre
13  30     2         55         post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) , [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for consecutive groups and pass to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and `sum`.

Last use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
a = np.sign(df['month_diff'])
g = a.ne(a.shift()).cumsum()
df1 = (df.groupby(['ID', g])
         .agg({'month_diff':'last', 'spend':'sum'})
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
df1['flag'] = np.select([df1['month_diff'].ge(-2) & df1['month_diff'].lt(0),
                         df1['month_diff'].gt(0) & df1['month_diff'].le(2)], 
                         ['pre','post'], default='another val')
print (df1)
   ID  month_diff  spend  flag
0  12          -2     20   pre
1  12           2     50  post
2  13          -2     35   pre
3  13           2     55  post
```

Comment: could you also let me know in case if no. of rows in positive and negative month_diff is NOT EQUAL(i.e. 2 -ve months but 6 +ve months. Your solution work perfectly fine but if in case I want to take sum of spend for 2months in negative and 4 months of spend for positive month_diff. how can I control the spend cumulation based on no. of months . Thanks

Comment: @Karan - Is possible post new question with these new data and expected output?